# I am getting error installing wgrib2 on Mac OS

Tags: python-3.x, macos

I need help installing wgrib2 on my macOS BigSur.
I have struggled with it for the past couple of days. I followed the instruction in https://bovineaerospace.wordpress.com/2017/08/20/how-to-install-wgrib2-in-osx/
But I am getting an error shown below when I compile.
Please what is causing the error and how can I resolve it.

```
(base) XXX@XXX-MBP grib2 % make
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
make: *** No rule to make target `uncomment', needed by `for'.  Stop.
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Successfully installed wgrib2 via mac port.
See link below.
https://ports.macports.org/port/wgrib2/

I first installed all the dependencies before installing the wgrib2.